# Why Would Someone Not Remove Their Armor?

Tags: armors

You pull up a stool at the bar next to a gentleman in full plate armor. The two of you strike up a conversation, but during the whole time, the man does not remove his armor, nor does he even raise his face plate. The armor must be cumbersome and heavy, but the man doesn't seem to mind. You're curious why he doesn't remove his armor, but you don't want to ask for fear of being rude.

**What reasons would someone have to not remove full plate armor?**

Ignore the fact that this person would need to eat, go to the bathroom, sleep, etc. He seems to function and move just fine, despite hot days.

I'm looking for a semi-believable reason that would convince a curious onlooker.

*EDIT: Realistic reasons would be best, as magic in this world is too rare to really consider. This is set in a fantasy world, not the world of Earth

Comment: Hi Jaustin, welcome to Worldbuilding! Do you want to find a real-world reason, or magical reasons should be also considered?

Comment: Thanks! Real-world reasons would be best. I'll make and edit.

Comment: he attending a convention, or shooting a movie, and armor takes too long to remove and put on.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific: this world in a fantasy one, so Halloween and movies don't exist.

Comment: What's the current level of technology? medieval? in other world, are plate armor contemporary?

Comment: The current level of tech is medieval. So people have seen knights and soldiers in plate armor before

Comment: if setting is medieval, he did not want to get out of the armor b/c he is on a lunch break from active guard duty (it requires a page to remove), or b/c he is afraid somebody will attack him

Comment: Hi, welcome to worldbuilding.se. Hope you have fun here. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and have a browse around the [help], to help you get a feel for how wb.se works. I suggest you add the medieval tag to your question on your next edit. Currently I think this is a little broad and opinion-based. You haven't provided any indication on what would be a good answer aside from no magic and medieval time. good luck and enjoy yourself.

Comment: You may need to edit this question to add more constraints, because there are many possible reasons for why he wouldn't remove the armor: it's welded shut, he's paranoid/always expecting a fight, he's doesn't want anyone to see him, he's a soldier/guard that's always on duty, he's a spy pretending to be a guard, ...

Comment: Because this is the *Fullmetal Alchemist* universe, and you're talking to Alphonse Elric.

Comment: Why is this gentleman sitting at a bar by himself, unable to eat or drink? Does he just enjoy the ambiance or something?

Comment: couple of misconceptions here, well fitted medieval armor while it had decent weight to it would be well supported such that it didn't feel any more cumbersome to wear than something like motorcycle or hockey padding. Also especially for later medieval plate armors they were designed to be hard to remove, you wouldn't want an errant sword swing to open your armor, so without a page or squire to help with his armor he may not be capable of removing all of it himself

Comment: @DBlint: Of course Hallowe'en exists, but everybody dresses up in scary suits and ties, or freaky t-shirts and jeans. - On weekends they play a fantasy RPG called "Papers and Paychecks".

Answer (score 6):

## "Uh, I'm a city guard and I'm on duty."

There is no *good*, *realistic* reason why somebody would wear armor all the time. It isn't good for the armor, which needs to be scoured after every use to prevent rust, and it isn't good for the wearers who will get skin problems from the sweaty/hot/wet padding.

But in a fantasty or pseudo-medieval setting with wandering adventurers, a trade city could allow visitors their swords, daggers, and axes, and ban any armor tougher than a leather jerkin. That saves them endless arguments about the length of a shortsword-or-knife or the nature of a battleaxe-or-woodaxe, and still gives the city guard a decisive edge over drunk caravan guards.

**But that doesn't explain the helmet.**

That is just weird, and it should be a sign for any character that *plot* is happening.

Comment: "on duty" - that explains why he's not drinking :)

Comment: @Alexander, he should be drinking (thin beer or watered wine, can't risk the water) to avoid collapse under that armor.

Answer (score 6):

*Knight:*  Say friend do you by chance know any man with red Hair and a white Streak in it?  He's not graying he just has a pure white streak in his hair.

*You:*  I don't know of any one with that description.

*Knight:*  Damn.

*You:* Why do you ask?

*Knight:*  He killed my father,  And I've sworn not to remove this armor untill my father is avenged.

You: Wow! how long ago did it happen?

*Knight:* It's nearing two years now.

*You:*  geez I'm so sorry.  You know I've got a friend who should meet, his name is Inigo Montoya

Answer (score 4):

A real-life reason:

The year is 2018. And the date is October 31.

Comment: Just because it's a short answer, does not mean it hasn't answered the question. Halloween is realistic reason why someone would be dressed like this.

Answer (score 2):

#### Disguise

What if you **are** the wanted man with the red hair with a white streak in it? If I was him I'd keep my helmet on in public.

#### Gender Discrimination

There are no official female knights. But I want to be one. I'm strong and skilled enough but I can't let anyone see inside my armor or helmet or I'll be thrown in jail or burned at the stake.

Answer (score 2):

There was a real reason knights made stupid things like that.

It was called "passage of arms", a promise linked to chivalry and the Lady of the knight. They promised her to be the bravest man by defending a bridge for a year (jousting against all the other knights who wanted to cross it), or going to jousts disguised with black armor and dramatic names like The Sorrowful Knight or The Heartbroken. Sometimes they wore tied a piece of clothing given by their Lady, as stupid as it looked.

It was something born from literature and minstrels that the knights later made real. Because it doesn't take much to convince a bunch of teenagers with money, time and a lot of physical training to do something stupid.

Your mystery man in plated could have sworn something like that and admit it proudly.

Answer (score 1):

**Cultural Norms**
For instance, all men must serve as guard in a place, and it rotates out to different people, but the custom is that you are considered an arm of the law not an individual, so the custom is that you never lower your faceplate or say your name when you serve. Some take this more seriously than others--the more seriously they take it the more likely they are to follow this custom to the letter.

**The sacred vow.**
He made a promise, and will not remove it until the promise is met.

**Psychological problems**
Paranoia, feeling naked without the armor, delusions that the armor is a part of their soul...you pick...

**Magical Reasons**
Mundane is best but...perhaps he's an elite solider of the king's army. Out of armor he's a paraplegic. To be able to move around properly he has to wear it fully.

**The helmet is stuck or bent into place**
A la A Knight's Tale the movie. When the main character masqueraded as a knight, he used the fact that the helmet was bent not to be able to remove it.

**A face that only a mother could love**
Character mentions that they are deformed, but respected as a knight and so never removes helmet in front of people.

However, if:

> You're curious why he doesn't remove his armor, but you don't want to ask for fear of being rude.

Then no reason would be given in the first place, correct? And this is not about the ACTUAL reason, but the excuse given or how it's passed off, yes?

So going to say--

**Everyone around you accepts it**

"Him? That's just Sir Larry. Pay 'em no heed. He comes in every night."

"Why does he keep his armor on?" you ask.

"Been that way since the war. He saved the village, so Sir Larry does what he pleases," the barkeep answers.

Answer (score 1):

Plain simple paranoia "what are you crazy? If I remove this armour all my enemies will choose that moment to strike!". Bare in mind this paranoia may or may not be justified,  they might be crazy or they may have just killed the head of the largest cartel in the city.

Full plate armour is *very* expensive and is certainly a status symbol. Maybe he just want's to show it off after he just got it that doesn't necessarily explain why he'd not draw up the face plate (unless the face plate is highly ornate).

Faith, religion makes people do some seemingly irrational things to those outside the faith. It's possible your knight was simply told by his local priest to not remove his armour for a while, perhaps out of penance, perhaps due to some vague omens in his dreams.

he's straight out of the fight and he just can't get it off. This might sound ridiculous but in the late medieval period blunt weapons were very common and its not out of the question that a heavy set of plate armour could be dented so much that it's difficult/unsafe to remove without aid from another person. Your knight simply wanted a rest and a chat before going to get it off with help from his squire.

He has erupted with hideous boils (potentially contagious) and is heading to the nearest healer keeping his face and body hidden in his plate armour in the mean time to save face.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons:

1) paranoid, feels naked and vulnerable, afraid to be stabbed in the back.

2) wanted. His face is posted all over town.

3) expecting the victim to come by anytime soon, better be armed and ready.

4) planning a robbery, though robbing a bar is not as profitable as robbing a bank.

5) cheating on his wife. Just in case she's around...